# how to optimize a query relating group by and order by

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `id` IN ( SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `name` )
```

How can we optimize this query?

Comment: indexes could help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
select t.*
from table_name t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from table_name t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

Then you want an index on `table_name(name, id)`:

```
create index idx_table_name_name_id on table_name(name, id);
```

Your version of the query is going to require aggregation for the subquery -- I don't think MySQL will rewrite it.  The aggregation can probably use the index.  However, writing the query using an `=` guarantees an optimal execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding an index on `(name, id)`.  This should greatly improve the performance the subquery, allowing MySQL to quickly lookup each `id` value in the outer query.

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON table_name (name, id);
```

Assuming `table_name` has many columns, then `SELECT *` would probably preclude the chance that any single index could speed up the outer query.  But, at least we can try optimizing the `WHERE IN` clause.

Comment: yes, I wanted to optimize the wherein clause, actually.